# Installing theme for Yii Application

Tags: php, yii, installation, themes, xampp

i'm new to Yii . i have downloaded one theme from "yii.themefactory.net" and i placed it in main configuration of my application.

i know that view is separate from model and controller and all operation in my application but im wondering how this new theme will be match to my controllers and models ,, do i have to add any codes in other directories ,,

i must say mmy question is general ,, i just started using Yii .  i have no idea how yii corresponds to theme.

please make me clear and tell me
which sources are better so download theme

Comment: You do realize that Yii is a Framework, not a CMS? So themes are in general pretty useless here.

Comment: i dont get what do you mean ,, i asked how does it work ,,

Comment: If you have this question, I suggest you try Drupal or Wordpress instead of Yii.

Comment: as i said i just started ,, no one is prefect at first dude ,

Comment: That was in no way meant to be offensive. Just telling, if you are thinking on using per-made themes instead of creating your own site, then I suggest you to use CMS not Frameworks.

Comment: but i can use themes in Yii right? why should i create my layout from scratch

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/149260/difference-between-a-cms-and-a-web-development-framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are thinking to add theme like Joomla or WordPress. YII is not like that.
In your Application's there is a layout folder inside views. In layout there is main.php.

```
Main.php in Layouts
```

Add your Header, footer and top menu HTML code here. and inplace of content

```
<?php echo $content; ?>
```

Links to the CSS / JS / Images should be like this.

```
<link href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

You need to add `<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/` for path.

**View Files**
Inside View add the content you want in that page.

**Controller:**
In your controller do like this

```
    public $layout='//layouts/main';
```

Hope this helps.